# apache server mapping to tomcat issues

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

I am working on the flex application. Back end is spring/Hibernate. The application is working fine in my local XP system.
When i am trying to deploy in the server i'm facing the issue.

**The issue is how to map the java in apache**

when i am by passing the apache & works in tomcat my application is working good. But not in the apache..

This can be fixed by mapping the java in apache.

I don't know how to map this. can u help me out

My server properties

**Linux lumiin.ch 2.6.18-028stab095.1 i686**

Regards Karthick

Comment: How do you map your apache to your tomcat?

Comment: I don't know how to map the apache ??  Can u guide me in steps

Comment: I mesread something. Let me type my answer

Answer (score 1):

I figerd you mean to reverse proxy your Tomcat.

This is done by adding the ProxyPassReverse and the ProxyPass directives to your apache conf

something like

```
ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPassReverse /foo/ http://example.com:8080/
ProxyPass /foo/ http://example.com:8080/
```